# How synchronize on object without locking?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have seen question [How do determine if an object is locked (synchronized) so not to block in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779795/how-do-determine-if-an-object-is-locked-synchronized-so-not-to-block-in-java)
But I have problem on which I can not figure out solution.
In my web application is process in which refresh of data container and that can take long time. Refresh is forced to be made in time intervals. Of course when one refresh is still on container working another cannot (to do not corrupt data in container).
I want to use background thread to refresh container. Multiple background workers can be working at the same time on multiple containers (different workers for different user sessions, every user session can have different data in their container).
Of course I can do `synchronize(myContainer)` in worker to force that any other worker is not currently updating this particular container. But I rather want to check if any worker is working on container and exit, if is. Also I would like to not change code of container, so I would like not to add ReentrantLock inside container class and lock on that.
So worker have `MyContainer` instance and want to determine if any other worker is currently refreshing this container instance.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an `AtomicBoolean`, put this code in your `MyContainer` class:

```
AtomicBoolean isRefreshing = new AtomicBoolean(false);

void refresh() {
  if ( isRefreshing.compareAndSet( false, true)) {
    try {
      // refresh
    } finally {
      isRefreshing.set( false);
    }
  }
}
```

If you can not touch MyContainer, maybe create a RefreshWrapper holding the AtomicBoolean and the MyContainer instance.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the containers in a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) and have the worker threads `poll` the queue i.e.

```
Container container;
while((container = queue.poll()) != null) {
    container.refresh();
}
```

Then you have two options depending on whether the containers are tracking when they are being refreshed.

- If they are then you can `offer` the refreshed containers back into the queue as soon as they're refreshed. You can use an `if(container.refreshTime < X)` guard to ensure that you don't refresh the container twice in the same time interval.
- If they are not then you can either

  - Use two `ConcurrentLinkedQueues` and alternate between them: `poll` on `queue1` and `offer` the refreshed container on `queue2`, and when `queue1` is empty sleep until the next time interval, at which point `poll` on `queue2` and `offer` the refreshed containers on `queue1`.
  - Or, keep an array of the containers in the main thread, and `offer` the containers back into the queue when the worker threads have finished refreshing all of the containers and have gone to sleep.

Comment: `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is non-blocking which means if the OP is not careful, the while loop can do some serious busy-spinning

Comment: @John Vint I'm assuming that the queue already holds all of the containers at the time that the worker threads are started, as would be the case if the containers are immediately re-added to the queue or are immediately added to another queue that is then alternated with the original queue.  If this isn't the case then a `BlockingQueue` would be the better choice - the loop in my answer wouldn't busy-spin if containers are simultaneously added and removed from the queue, but it would run the risk of prematurely terminating.

Comment: @JohnVint: Actually, my answer has the same drawback, but I think limiting the frequency of refreshes is beyond the scope of this question, and the OP should have something in place to address that. Otherwise, a `ScheduledExecutorService` would be good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pre-check if the object has not already been locked by some other thread, this should be possible with [Thread.holdsLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#holdsLock%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

If this is not enough, look into the [advanced lock classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html). These locks provide the rich set of features (check that is waiting on the lock, try to lock with time out, lock interruptably, etc). They should provide enough features to solve your problem.