# try-lock to a synchronized statement

Tags: java, multithreading

Java [synchronized statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) is a way of protecting a data resource from being access simultaneously by multiple threads. It can be done via doing *synchronize* to an object X as a critical section or mutex.

```
class MyClass
{
    int a;
    object X = new object();

    void Foo()
    {
        synchronized(X)
        {
            a++;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way of doing try-lock to X instead of lock like this?

```
void Foo()
{
    if(try_synchronized(X)==true)
    {
        a++;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779795/how-do-determine-if-an-object-is-locked-synchronized-so-not-to-block-in-java) say that ReentrantLock is the alternative way, but *synchronized* keyword is implemented under Java VM, so this question is different.

Comment: Mentioned the difference.

Comment: What it's saying is that you can't do such a thing with `synchronized`. The solution is with the `java.util.concurrent` types.

Comment: I don't know that I've ever seen an application program use `lock.tryLock()` or anything like it.   I don't think its a smart thing to do.  If a thread needs to test a lock, that probably means the thread is responsible for more than one thing.  That's bad design.  Instead of one thread with N responsibilities, it would be better to have N threads, each with one responsibility.

Comment: There are uses of `lock.tryLock()`. See for example the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker.html) of `ManagedBlocker`.